# Force-Directed Graph 101

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, graph, d3.js

I'd like to draw a simple Force-Directed Graph (2 nodes with 1 link) using the d3.js library.

I tried to modify the json file from the example [Here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045) to take only 2 nodes and 1 link but it didn't seem to work.

How can I do it?

Comment: There are literally hundreds of examples of D3's force layout. They should give you a farily good idea of what to do. Also "it didn't seem to work" isn't really an error description that allows us to help you.

Comment: Thanks Lars for your response. I know you're right saying that "it doesn't seem to work" is not helping but there's no error log otherwise I would've published it. It just returns a blank page. If you copy the example as it is, it works fine, but when you modify the JSON file to keep 2 nodes and 1 link, it returns a blank page.

Comment: @user1885868, my advice for you would be to cool off a little bit from coding and watch this video (http://vimeo.com/29458354), or do something else, and then come back to original probem, you'll have a different perspective for sure. :)

Comment: Could post the data you're using? Remember that you have to keep a link that's between the two nodes you keep.

Comment: Thanks my friends, I just figured out the problem, my error was actually a very stupid one:
I was leaving a comma after the final line of the list of nodes or links in the JSON file.

Comment: It seems like you weren't using the inspector to help you debug. Since that became standard in Firefox and Chrome it's been a lot easier to troubleshoot javascript. That's the first thing to examine when you get a blank screen.